# QGIS: default selection distance for "Select Feature(s)"?

Tags: qgis, select, gui

This is such a beginner's question...

(QGIS 3.26)
Where can I find and modify the distance used for the default "select feature()s" tool?

[image]

I want to quickly select a number of points.

when single-clicking I have to be (too) precise 'on the dot' to select a point.
the value in use seems to be zoom-independent

For the moment, I draw an area over the point to select it.

But it would be speedier to increase that search value.

Where does that value/setting hide?

Comment: there are more select options (radius, by polygon, freehand, expression etc.) https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#selecting-features ) its available in a drop down plus use the shortcuts manually selecting

Comment: the other selection methods are either area selectors or require a numerical entry.
that disrupts the workflow even more.
the manual does not state the options governing them

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a small plugin called 'Select By Distance' which you may find useful. You can download it from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/benwirf/select_by_distance) by clicking on the Code button and selecting Download Zip.

[image]

You can then go to Manage and Install Plugins in QGIS and use the option to Install from Zip.

[image]

Once installed and activated, the plugin will add an action icon to the Selection Toolbar:

[image]

When you click the action, you will get an input dialog where you can enter the search distance. This distance is in the units of the canvas CRS. After you enter the distance you will see a rubber band following the mouse cursor which shows the selection area. If you want to change the distance while the tool is active, just right-click on the map canvas.

Short demo below:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the effort.  
I'll check it out. if it works as described, it'll come in handy soon

Answer (score 0):

QGIS>Settings>Options>Map Tools[image]

QGIS 3.26 used.

Comment: This seems to affect the **identify** tool  

It does not seem to change the behaviour of the select-features tool